# MVC 4, Entity Framework 5: Result set will return unfixed number of columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures

I have a requirement to get payroll data from database and generate report in excel format.

The first 10 columns are employee data, no issue. The issue is starting from column 11, it's payroll data.

The number of payroll data is according to number of available payroll data of the selected month. Meaning, this month may has 15 payroll data, which means 15 columns; but next month may has 20 columns. So the number of columns is not fixed.

As I understand from working with EF, we need to return a specific number of columns to tell EF exactly how many columns will be returned from one result set.

So what should I do to manage this type of scenario? My project use mainly EF for data retrieval. Or is there any alternative I can use?

Thanks

Comment: Have you want to use "dynamic columns" mapping for a table? I have no idea if you can't show any model mapping details & existing EF code related to your issue.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Thanks for your comment. I'm unable to show any model of existing EF code because I have no idea how to do anything like that. Appreciate if you can share some links about the dynamic columns mapping that you referring to